# How to delete multiple lines from txt using php

Tags: php

Hello is there a way to delete multiple lines from a text file by using php code?
for example `text.php`

```
<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>
<a>4</a>
<a>5</a>
<a>6</a>
<a>7</a>
```

i would like to delete the first 5 lines without actually using the content to delete.

Comment: Yes, just get the file and overwrite it with the data, just without the first 5 lines

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php look at the example #2 and #3. Its really easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$file =  "yourfile.txt"
$lines = file( $file );
$less = array_slice($lines, 4);
file_put_contents( $file, $less );
```

(You can't edit the file particular, you have to overwrite it.)

**EDIT:** delete 3-5:

```
$file =  "yourfile.txt"
$lines = file( $file );
$end = array_slice($lines, 4);
array_splice($lines, 2);
$less = array_merge( $lines, $end );
file_put_contents( $file, $less );
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Comment: i see, what if i were to delete 3-5 not the first 5 lines